# Excel VBA - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vba, excel, object

I'm using a long process which creates and populates a series of 'route' workbooks and populates a master 'summary' workbook while doing this.

In brief, the error occurs immediately at the start of importing the data from the route workbook as soon as I try to use the relevant worksheet in the summary.

While quoting the entire code would be impractical, I have copied from where I think to be 'relevant' here:

```
        ' Get Route Number
    RNum = wshCtrl.Cells(2, 2 + i).Value    ' Number for routes being processed (blank if not processed)
    RawRNum = wshCtrl.Cells(4, 2 + i).Value ' Raw Number
    ' Get Route Direction
    RDir = wshCtrl.Cells(9, 2 + i).Value
    ' Get Name of Worksheet
    NamewshRoute = "Route " & RawRNum & " - " & RDir
    ' Check if Route Worksheet exists
    Set wshRoute = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If Route Worksheet doesn't exist and Route being processed
    If wshRoute Is Nothing And RNum <> "" Then
        ' Create Route Worksheet
        ' Copy Template
        wshTemplate.Copy After:=wshTemplate
        ' Rename Copied Template
        Worksheets("Template (2)").Name = NamewshRoute
        ' Set as Route Worksheet
        Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)
        ' Enter Route Number and Direction
        wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value = RNum
        wshRoute.Cells(2, 4).Value = RDir

    ' If Route Worksheet doesn't exist and Route isn't being processes
    ElseIf wshRoute Is Nothing Then
        ' Do Nothing

    ' Else Route Worksheet already exists and Route being processed
    Else

        ' Update Progress Bar
        Percent = j / (NumRoutes + 0.5) - (1 / (NumRoutes + 1) * 8 / 8)
        RefreshStatusBar Percent, "Processing " & NamewshRoute, "Initialising Route"

        ' Update Date
        wshRoute.Range("AW9").Value = Month & Year
```

The error occurs on one of the following two lines:

```
wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value = RNum
```

or

```
wshRoute.Range("AW9").Value = Month & Year
```

depending on whether the worksheet exists or not.

Note that:

1. Option Explicit is present at the top of the code.
2. As far as I can tell all variables are defined and set appropriately.
3. I have used the debugging process and using 'Add Watch' have confirmed that wshRoute is set appropriately and so are RNum, Month and Year.
4. wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value returns the correct value and so does wshRoute.Range("AW9").Value.
5. The only inconsistency I can see is that when I look further into the properties of wshRoute, the properties 'OnCalculate' through to 'OnSheetDeactivate' all have a value of . Not sure if this is relevant or not.

This code worked fine (I have been using for approximately a year) until I added another macro at the start. The new macro opens a different workbook and creates 'data' files. It doesn't interact with the 'Summary' workbook in any way. If I run the code without the extra new macro, it runs fine again.

Any suggestions please fire them through. This is high priority for me so I will be testing promptly.

Thanks, Cameron

Comment: `opens a different workbook` time to qualify your sheets with workbooks as well: `Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)`.

Comment: Wait, something is fishy. You set `wshRoute` to something then immediately after `If wshRoute Is Nothing`????

Comment: Use `Set wshRoute = WorkSheets(NamewshRoute)` instead of `Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)`.

Comment: Try Set wshRoute = wshTemplate.Parent.Sheets (NameshRoute)

Comment: @findwindow. On error Resume Next.... If it doesn't yet exist...

Comment: @AbeGold uh, I don't get OP's logic/goal. Set to nothing, but try to set to something then check if it's nothing then set it to something? Or something else? @_@

Comment: Set to Nothing to clear old instances. Set. If still = Nothing then sheet doesn't exist. If so, Create sheet and assign

Comment: @AbeGold thanks! Edit: like your groovy way of qualifying via `parent`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses all. @pcw just tried your solution. (Makes sense to start at the top...) It didn't work though :(

Comment: @AbeGold could you please clarify what your "Set wshRoute = wshTemplate.Parent.Sheets (NameshRoute)" does? Do I use this in place of "Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)"?

Comment: Yes. It's picking up the same instance of excel which seems to be the issue

Comment: @AbeGold still no luck :( same error in the same place

Comment: For `wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value = RNum` to fail because `wshRoute` in Nothing, the previous line `Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)` should *also* fail - that should be the line with the error...

Comment: The problem may be earlier in code. AS Fidwindow said, qualify your instances of Excel. Before openi NV the second Excel file, set the active workbook to a variable. Use that variable when setting Amy other Objects of the WorkBook. I wb1.Sheets (...)

Comment: @TimWilliams that was my thinking too...

Comment: @AbeGold bugger missed the first comment! If that's the solution I'll be kicking myself because I should have been doing that anyway!

Comment: As long as `wshRoute` can be set successfully, the fact it might be pointing to a different workbook would not cause the error on the line `wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value = RNum`

Comment: @TimWilliams you were correct... error still present

Comment: Typically when things make no sense here, it's because some vital piece is missing.  What you're seeing isn't explained by what you posted.  Unless you're willing to share the whole workbook it seems unlikely we can help much beyond the suggestions already made.

Comment: @TimWilliams Bugger, that will be hard due to the size, number of workbooks involved and confidentiality... I will ponder over the weekend. Thanks Tim

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is that the exact error you get?  I'm not sure that's a VBA error...  "Object variable or with block variable not set" is what I get in VBA if I try to assign a value when the sheet object is Nothing.  Try unloading any add-ins you might have installed.

Comment: @TimWilliams the error I get, word for word, is "Run-time error '1004': Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Any add-ins or other similar things installed ?

Comment: @TimWilliams There is one, but it's an in-house developed one and haven't had any problems with it recently. I tried turning it off but the same error occurs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of back and forth... thanks to all those who contributed.

The problem was **I was trying to modify protected sheets**

I found this by placing `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the line causing the error. When this happened, the original *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'* error was substituted for a *'The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only.'* error.

I fixed it by making sure all of my worksheets were unprotected when the macro was running.

On a side note - I got caught out with not qualifying my sheets with workbooks.

Thanks again for all of your suggestions.

Comment: I still think your real problem was being masked by an add-in: "normally" (without disabling events) you would have seen the error message about a protected sheet, but the add-in was triggering that error first, and giving you the (non-VBA) "object reference" message instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these debug statements and see what you get:

```
Set wshRoute = Sheets(NamewshRoute)

Debug.Print wshRoute Is Nothing
Debug.Print wshRoute.Name & " is in workbook " & wshRoute.Parent.Name
Debug.Print wshRoute.Cells(2, 3) Is Nothing
Debug.Print "RNum is type " & TypeName(RNum)

wshRoute.Cells(2, 3).Value = RNum
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Results: **Debug.Print wshRoute Is Nothing** = "False"
**Debug.Print wshRoute.Name & " is in workbook " & wshRoute.Parent.Name** = "Route 1 - AtoB is in workbook February 2016 PT Summary.xlsm"
**Debug.Print wshRoute.Cells(2, 3) Is Nothing** = "False"
**Debug.Print "RNum is type " & TypeName(RNum)** = "RNum is type String"

Comment: And you still get that error on the last line?  Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` (set back to True afterwards) just before that line, in case something is being triggered by an event fired off by updating the worksheet.

Comment: Aha! I did this and get a new error telling me the sheet is protected or read only. Although I can't discover why because at that stage of the macro all sheets have been unprotected so I CAN modify them as such... The error I get is: "Run-time error '1004': The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only. To modify a protected cell..."

Comment: Progress! I unprotected the new worksheet immediately after I created it and it skipped this step. It has then passed the initial error and gives me a similar error later on in the process. I have a hunch it'll be the same issue and my unprotecting at the start of the piece is malfunctioning somewhere. Leave it with me and I'll let you know how I get on!